Как сделать чтобы выбиралось случайное фото из папки?
Есть программа обрабатывающая фото.
В ней есть строка:
unsigned char* data = stbi_load("C:\\Users\\tpog\\Documents\\images\\picture_(1).png", &w, &h, nullptr, 3);

Она загружает фото по ссылке.
Можно ли сделать чтобы ссылка была на случайное фото из папки?
Например, чтобы она стала:  "C:\Users\tpog\Documents\images\picture_(2).png".
Скрин кода, если понадобится:
1: 

Да, можно, загрузите список файлов директории в вектор/массив и выберите случайный индекс

см. std::filesystem::directory_iterator
